# problem of numeric sequence

Tags: calculus, analysis

Give an example of a sequence $(A_n)$ which is not convergent but the sequence $(B_n)$ defined by $\displaystyle B_n = \frac{A_1+A_2+\cdots+A_n}{n}$ is convergent.

Comment: Harmonic series maybe? just a quick guess,

Answer (score 3):

One example is: $A_n = (-1)^n$.

Comment: but is Bn converge then??

Comment: Yes, because $A_1 + \ldots + A_n = 0$ for even $n$ and $= -1$ for odd $n$. Apply squeeze theorem.

Comment: This doesn't generalize the result..

Comment: i also thought about such (An)

Comment: What do you mean by "This doesn't generalize the result.." ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider the alternating $0,1$ sequence i.e. 
$$A_n = 0 \mbox{ if $n$ is odd} $$
$$A_n =1 \mbox{ if $n$ is even }$$

Then $B_n \to 1/2$ but as $A_n$ is oscillatory, it does not converge. For more details, refer Cesaro sums and Cesaro means.